# Proof of "Lagrange Lemma"

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, irreducible-polynomials

Can anyone share a link of proof of the following fact ?

> Let $f(x) \in K[x] $ be an irreducible polynomial with $n$ distinct roots $r_i$ and let $g(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and  $h(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ be polynomials in $K[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n] $ such that any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ for which $g(r_1, r_2,...,r_n)$ is different from $g(r_{\pi(1)} , r_{\pi(2)} ,...,r_{\pi(n)})$ we have $h(r_1, r_2,...,r_n)$ is different from $h(r_{\pi(1)} , r_{\pi(2)} ,...,r_{\pi(n)})$. Then $g(r_1, r_2,...,r_n) \in K(h(r_1, r_2,...,r_n))$.

Comment: Is $f$ irreducible in $K$, or do its roots lie in $K$ ? One thing usually contradicts the other.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I mean (f irreducible in the field K) with (r_i distnict roots). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you know about Galois theory ?